# How to enable thirdparty cookies in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart

I couldn't find an alternative to do

```java
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Log.d(AppConstants.TAG,"SDk version above android L so forcibaly enabling ThirdPartyCookies");
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
    }
```

using [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview)

How do we do that in flutter_inappwebview ?

Comment: Did you find a way around this?